# Want to check my old trip ticket

Tags: tickets, flight-search-engines

I was gone on my last trip from august 5th to 15th and I visited 3 countries. I travel with Sri-Lanka airline. I have lost my physical ticket. I want to view my whole ticket information online.

**How can I view past ticket information online?**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: JS Lavertu i just want to ask , is there any website available which store the old ticket record.

Comment: I suggest you mention the airline you traveled with, this will help pinpointing an answer.

Comment: JS Lavertu mention it in my post

Comment: What does the tag "old-trafford" have to do with this question?

Answer (score 1):

As you had a paper ticket, one might guess you booked through a travel agency, who may still have your information in their reservation system.

Sri Lankan Airline will have your booking/ticket data in their system and can likely look it up for you (perhaps with a fee involved depending on how long ago you flew).  They would likely need your PNR (record locator / reservation id), last name and perhaps a third identifier (credit card used, first flight number, date, etc)

If you had the flights credited to your frequent flyer account, you can look up dates, flights and perhaps fare class through your frequent flyer account.

But as a general rule, airlines do not maintain online records of past flights through third parties.  Nor do they make them easily accessible through their public website.